# Bounding expectations of Gaussian integrals

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, inequality, optimal-transport

I have quite a few questions regarding [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.07348.pdf), and in particular APPENDIX D, which contains the proof of propostion C.2:

With the following definitions in mind,

[image]

[image]

(denoting $\hat P \equiv \sum_{i=1}^n \delta_{X_i}/n$ the empirical measure).  I believe there is a typo and that $\mu$ should be a $P$.  Anyways, I am stuck on the *first step* of the proof, primarily because I'm a moron.  It says this:

[image]

Here are the links to [Maurer and Pontil (2010)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1002.0832.pdf) and [Gine and Nikl (2016)](http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/%7Enickl/Site/__files/FULLPDF.pdf), although truly (for me at least) only God knows where to find any of the arguments that correspond to this paper.  ***How do you argue that $$\mathbb{E} \sup_{c, S} |\mathbb{E}_P f_{c,S} - \mathbb{E}_{\hat P} f_{c,S}| \leq \frac{\sqrt{2 \pi}}{n} \mathbb{E} \sup_{c, S} |\sum_{i=1}^n g_i f_{c, S}(X_i)| \quad \textbf{?}$$
I am genuinely and absolutely lost.***

I understand the rest of the proof except for the above two inequalities and this next picture:

[image]

In particular the first and third inequalities make no sense.  If at all possible, any help will be massively appreciated.  I will gladly make a very large bounty for this if someone is able to help me understand what's going on.